# how to avoid using remember_token without model in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use an old database with a table called client without a field
   `remember_token`, I use query builder for all actions, that means without a model, so how to avoid updating the `remember_token` when I logout

Comment: I am not sure if you are using `client` table to store user authentication information but if yes, then see [this](https://laravel.io/forum/05-21-2014-how-to-disable-remember-token)

Comment: but i don't use a user model !! i just used query builder for other actions !!

Comment: Then I can say if its not used for authentication  then it will not matter for any login or logout actions.Its a custom column in your table. Also then it should not update when logout happens

Answer (score 0):

you can find the solution here with different opinions, 
i hope it helps.. [how to disable remember token](https://laravel.io/forum/05-21-2014-how-to-disable-remember-token)

Comment: nothing work. just i try now to add it to my client table and create a model

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

Please update **User** model with below function

```
 /**
   * Overrides the method to ignore the remember token.
   */
  public function setAttribute($key, $value)
  {
    $rsltRememberTokenAttribute = $key == $this->getRememberTokenName();
    if (!$rsltRememberTokenAttribute)
    {
      parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: but i don't use a user model !! i just used query builder for other actions !!

Comment: @HaithemKdous: Ohh that means this column not affected when you logout because this ```remember_token``` is just one type of column